# ValueError on Python Enum when comma seperated

Tags: python

Consider the following code.
How does python interpret class `RottenFruit` when it is comma separated? Is this legal? If yes, what is the use case?

```
from enum import Enum
class Fruit(Enum):
     Apple = 4
     Orange = 5
     Pear = 6 
a = Fruit(5)

class RottenFruit(Enum):
     Apple = 4,
     Orange = 5,
     Pear = 6
print(Fruit(5))
print(RottenFruit(5))
```

output:

```
Fruit.Orange
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\tests\sandbox.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(RottenFruit(5))
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\enum.py", line 291, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\enum.py", line 533, in __new__
    return cls._missing_(value)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\enum.py", line 546, in _missing_
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: 5 is not a valid RottenFruit
```

Comment: I disagree with the "put on hold as off-topic" assessment. The OP is asking why they don't just get a simple syntax error for their use of commas. This is interesting and I didn't get it at first either. Edit: now it has been marked as a duplicate, but there is no link to the supposed original question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second snippet is equivalent to this:

```
class RottenFruit(Enum):
     Apple = (4,)
     Orange = (5,)
     Pear = 6
```

In other words, `Apple` and `Orange` are each tuples of length one.

Let me add a quick explanation. You are running into the combination of two Python features here. One is that you can assign multiple things at once, like this:

```
 x = 7
 y = 8
 y, x = x, y  # Now x = 8 and y = 7
 q = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 x, m, *r, y = q  # Even fancier: now x = 1, m = 2, r = [3, 4] and y = 5
```

The other is that parsing rules of Python always allow a trailing comma in a list; this is useful for having a list spanning multiple lines look a bit cleaner, and allows a one-element tuple to be defined with e.g. `(1,)`. You have found a way to combine these rules in a way that's not really useful, but isn't worth preventing.

Comment: it comes as a natural instinct to put the comma while using enum in c++.